# How to Make Different Instances of an Object Have Different Sprites

Tags: sprites, gameobject, game-maker-dnd

In Game Maker, I am trying to make it so that three instances of an object have three different sprites. Using DnD, what would be the optimal way to do this? If it helps, the three instances are different sizes and are in separate, fixed places.

EDIT: I have added the following, and it gives an error that the global variable has not been set.
[image: administrater code]
[image: error message]
[image: text code]
[image: load order]

Comment: What's in the step event?

Comment: @boneco It just opens and closes an ini file. I have not worked on that part of my game yet.

Comment: Do you try to pass the value of the global variable to this file.ini in the step event?

Comment: @boneco No it just opens and closes the ini file every step without doing anything to the file.

Comment: Please upload your project to google drive and give me the link. From the images I can not identify what is wrong.

Comment: @boneco https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xWota0WfzcwvYGHY4zFVwS0vXDwNQfDp

Comment: You have to give me the whole folder. Go to documents, select the game folder, copy it to your desktop, compress it and then upload it to google drive.

Comment: @boneco That's what I thought I uploaded. How do I upload what you want?

Comment: You just passed me the file.yyp.

Comment: @boneco You have the whole file, it just looks like you only have that because folders only show up as flat bars. Hit download all in the top right corner to get the whole file.

Comment: I edited my answer. The problem is happening because of the changes you made to the size of the objects in the room. Delete and add them again without making these modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To do this, you will need:**

- 1 controller/administrator/creator object (`obj_Hades` in my project)
- 1 global variable (`global.number` in my project)

The controller object (`obj_Hades`) will basically serve for you to declare the global variable (`global.number`).

**Note that a sprite contains 3 images/frames:**

[image]

**In the controller object (obj_Hades):**

[image]

Be careful to place the controller object to be initialized first (see lower left corner of image above).

**In the object to have three different shapes:**

[image]

Remember to set the `image_speed` variable to 0, so that you don't run an animation.

**Result:**

[image]

**Reference:**

https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/001_gml%20language%20overview/variables/global%20variables.html

---

**If you have separated the images:**

[image]

Just make use of `IF'S`.

---

**EDIT 1**

**Test done with your project:**

[image]

I deleted the 3 objects and added them again. I realized that the ones you had placed in the room were different sizes, I don't know where you modified them, but apparently that was the cause of the problem.

Comment: I have the controller object initialized first as shown in the photo but for some reason, I keep getting an error saying that the global variable has not yet been set.

Comment: @K.O. Make an addition showing what you did and add to the question.

Comment: I have added the additions to the question.